# ¿Como puedo modificar este programa de manera que calcule el promedio de calificaciones del grupo?

Tags: c

Se como modificarlo si el ingreso de datos fuera de números pero acá el ingreso de datos es de letras y eso me complica.

Intenté meter un contador dentro del ciclo `while` pero creo que no se va incrementando por que a la hora de hacer el calculo `promedio = totalCuentas / contadorCalificaciones` e imprimo el promedio mediante `printf` me tira 0.
El `totalCuentas` es igual a `cuentaA + CuentaB + CuentaC + cuentaD + CuentaF`.
Espero que lo de arriba se haya entendido.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int calificacion, cuentaA=0, cuentaB=0, cuentaC=0, cuentaD 0, cuentaF=0;             

    printf("Introduzca la letra que corresponde a la calificacion.\n");
    printf("Introduzca el caracter EOF para finalizar la entrada de datos.\n");


    while ( ( calificacion = getchar() ) != EOF ) 
    { 
        switch ( calificacion ) 
        {
        case 'A': 
        case 'a':
            ++cuentaA; 
            break;

        case 'B': 
        case 'b':
            ++cuentaB; 
            break;

        case 'C': 
        case 'c':
            ++cuentaC; 
            break;

        case 'D': 
        case 'd':
            ++cuentaD; 
            break;

        case 'F': 
        case 'f':
            ++cuentaF; 
            break;

         case '\n':
         case '\t': 
         case ' ': 
             break;

         default: 
             printf( "Introdujo una letra incorrecta." );  
             printf( " Introduzca una nueva calificacion.\n" ); 
             break; 
        }
    }

    printf( "\nLos totales por calificacion son:\n" ); 
    printf( "A: %d\n", cuentaA );
    printf( "A: %d\n", cuentaB );
    printf( "A: %d\n", cuentaC );
    printf( "A: %d\n", cuentaD );
    printf( "A: %d\n", cuentaF );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es asignar un valor numérico a cada nota:

```
int total = cuentaA * 4 + cuentaB * 3 + cuentaC * 2 + cuentaD * 1 /* cuentaF = 0 */;
double promedio = ((double)total) / (cuentaA + cuentaB + cuentaC + cuentaD + cuentaF);
```

Tienes que darle un peso a cada nota, si no es imposible calcular un promedio. El peso es lo que te permite comparar unas notas con otras.